# Is there any way to avoid putting business logic in Execute method and define say 4 functions for different business logics

Tags: .net, quartz.net

Is there any way to define say 4 functions in our job class (which implements the `IJob` interface) and use them dynamically in quartz_jobs.xml file.

Right now the only way is to put business logic in the `Execute` method. But I want to define my own methods and use that name in `<job-type>` tag. Like say I defined 2 methods `SendMail1()` and `SendMail2()` and no execute method is there in my job class. Now I want to call it like:

```
<job-type>
    ClassLibrary1.Class1.SendMail1, ClassLibrary1
</job-type>
```

*Requirement is urgent*. If anybody has any idea, please send it.

Thanks in advance,
Akki J

Comment: I removed your email address from the post.  Answers should be posted here.  It doesn't help SO for answers to be sent directly in email.

Comment: no problems, i copied the link and can check periodically here only

Answer (score 0):

Add additional methods to your class as you describe.

In your Execute method use one of your job data values to determine which other method to call.